# Understanding Django Class-Based (DetailView and View)

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm transitioning some Function-Based Views to Class-Based Views in order to make my views more readable. But I am not understanding quite well the use of `DetailView` and how I can actually integrate it to my code in order to pass a `slug` into my function.

For now, I am using `View` and passing the `slug` into my function as below:

```
#urls.py
path('preview/<slug:slug>/', views.Preview.as_view(), name='toPreview')

#views.py 
@method_decorator(auth0_login_required, name='dispatch')
class Preview(View):
    template_name = 'authenticated/preview.html'

    @card_is_chosen
    def get(self, slug, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        person = get_object_or_404(Person, slug=slug, status=True)
        ...        
        return render(request, self.template_name, {...})
```

*I'm am also not quite sure if it's the best practice, in case it is then what does DetailView offer?*

---

**EDIT:** Trying to use DetailView as mentionned in the comments, how can I fix this error ?

```
#urls.py
path('preview/<slug:slug>/', views.Preview.as_view(), name='toPreview')

#views.py 
@method_decorator(auth0_login_required, name='dispatch')
class Preview(DetailView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'preview.html'

    @card_is_chosen
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        print(slug) 
        #slug is not defined, how should I fetch slug parameter?
        ...

        return render(request, self.template_name, {...})
```

**Traceback:**

```
File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\env\src\...\apps\businesscards\decorators.py", line 60, in wrap
    return function(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\env\src\...\apps\businesscards\views.py", line 160, in get
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, slug=slug, status=True)
NameError: name 'slug' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your slug field is called `slug`, you just need to specify the `model` and `template_name` in your detail view. The detail view will take care of fetching the person with that slug.

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

@method_decorator([auth0_login_required, card_is_chosen] name='dispatch')
class PersonDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'authenticated/preview.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        get_context_data is one of the important hooks in generic class
        based views. It lets you add extra variables to the template context
        """
        context = super(PersonDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['extra'] = 'extra value'
        return context
```

In the above, I've assumed that it's ok to decorate the `dispatch` method with `card_is_chosen`. If that's not the case you could add `method_decorator(card_is_chosen, name='get')` instead. I've added an `get_context_data` - it's not required for the code above, but it might be useful for some of the `...` code from your question that you didn't show.

If you are overriding the `get` method, I would use usual signature `def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):` then fetch slug for `self.kwargs`

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    slug = self.kwargs['slug']
```

You should usually avoid overriding `get` and `post` for generic class-based-views. You risk losing functionality or having to duplicate code. There are normally more specific attributes or methods that you can override.

Finally, don't assume that class based views are always better. Personally, I would find the following function-based-view easier to read than your `Preview` view.

```
@auth0_login_required
@card_is_chosen
def person(request, slug):
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, slug=slug, status=True)
    template_name = 'authenticated/preview.html'
    ...
    return render(request, template_name, {...})
```

Comment: While trying to use DetailView without overriding the get method, I get `name 'slug' is not defined`, where should I define it? I also tried to with `slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'`

Comment: That's not enough information for me to understand the problem. Please  edit your question to show the URL pattern and view that you tried, and the full traceback.

Comment: You can get the slug from `self.kwargs['slug']`. But note my warning about not overriding `get()` in generic class-based-views. If you call `get_object_or_404` yourself, you are duplicating the work that the detail view already does for you.

Comment: Oh I see, make sense, it's that part that I was having trouble with, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `DetailView` as below

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(card_is_chosen, name='get')
class Preview(DetailView):
    template_name = 'authenticated/preview.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Person, slug=self.kwargs['slug'], status=True)
```

access object in template with variable/name `object`

Answer (score 0):

Well the advantage of using CBVs is that you can re-use functionality both from other django CBVs or from your own classes/mixins. This results in having a more DRY code.

I've written a lengthy tutorial exactly about this which I recommend reading before starting to use CBVs: https://spapas.github.io/2018/03/19/comprehensive-django-cbv-guide/

Now, on your specific example: You rarely need to inherit from `View` - instead you inherit from sublasses of View, for example `DetailView` as you mention. Now, you could implement the `Preview` view like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import DetailView


class Preview(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = 'authenticated/preview.html'
    mode = Person
```

I'm not sure what the `@card_is_chosen` decorator does but the above has the same functionality as your example (I've changed `auth0_login_required` with `login_required` because I also don't know what `auth0_login_required` does). Notice that you don't need to redefine get nor you need to call any code for retrieving the object instance based on the slug.

Comment: `auth0_login_required` is not necessarily the same as `login_required` so I don't think you can use `LoginRequiredMixin`.

Comment: Probably you are right - the thing is that it's much better using Mixins instead of method decorators.